# What kind of waves can be/are produced by accelerating strong /weak forces

Tags: waves, weak-interaction, strong-force

Accelerating masses are now confirmed to produce gravitational waves. Also it is known that accelerating charges (electrical) produce EM waves. But what kind of waves are produced when particles interacting via strong or weak force accelerate. Are waves even produced at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Are there weak force waves?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/223424/50583)

Comment: There are no waves in QM? Would Schroedinger agree with that?