# Are electromagnetic and gravitational waves the only known types of waves that can travel in empty space?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, gravity

Besides electromagnetic and graviational waves, are there any other waves known to travel through empty space?

Comment: All particles? If you interpret electrons, protons, etc... as being described by waves.

Comment: Thanks, yes. Thinking a bit more about it, I think what I mean is waves associated with a force.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/223424/are-there-weak-force-waves

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.